# User input in repeated grid to fill dynamic dropdown

Tags: orbeon

I am building an Orbeon form where people can add information to a repeated grid, e.g. Name, Age.

Later in the form, there will be a 'Friend' section that will reuse data from the repeated grid.

I can synchronize the data using `<fr:synchronize-repeated-content>`, but is it possible to reuse the data from the repeated grid in a dynamic dropdown instead?

A dynamic dropdown could make this form much shorter, compared to `<fr:synchronize-repeated-content>`, as only a few of the rows in the repeated grid will need more data later in the form (only few friends from a long list of names in the repeated grid).

It is currently not possible for this form to use any web services.

Comment: Also, I added a +1 from you on [RFE 4182](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4182). -Alex

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't directly populate a dropdown based on data entered in a repeated grid earlier in the form. As you suggested, using another repeated grid and `<fr:synchronize-repeated-content>` is a workaround. But being able to directly populate a dropdown would definitely make sense, and this is covered by [request for enhancement 4182](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4182).